# Getting shared preference from class extending service

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I am currently working on an android project and that has a user interface to configure a background service.

I have successfully opened and modified the values within the apps preference file but I am then trying to open the shared preference file within the service class but I am getting a null pointer exception.

I'm using the following code to open the file

```
SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
```

I'm then accessing the shared prefs using the following but when I debug I don't think it gets this far, I think it fails on the line above.

```
if (isPowerConnected() && !wakeLock.isHeld() && settings.getBoolean("appEnabled", true))
```

Below is the exception that is thrown.

```
10-28 01:02:37.453: E/EnableWakeLock(18665): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 01:02:37.453: W/System.err(18665): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 01:02:37.453: W/System.err(18665):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:153)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you try to read a SharedPreferences from a Service you should read it via

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()
```

instead of

```
this.getSharedPreferences()
```

getDefaultSharedPreferences() takes a Context - your Service as a parameter. Please refer to the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context